# Would this pair of adjectives be considered "coordinating" and require a comma?

Tags: adjectives

Please request that your sealed, official transcripts be sent directly to the school.

Answer (score 6):

It depends. Are the "official transcripts" sealed, or are the transcripts "official" and "sealed"? If "sealed" is describing "official transcripts", then there is no need for a comma. Two or more adjectives are coordinating if the adjectives arranged differently still convey the same meaning.